# Open editDialog dialog box in tabular data

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to open a editdialog box of jQuery in my tabular data.

It have one column at the end where that data is edited. When it is clicked. It will open a view on top of the current view, without changing the current view.(like a modal we can say but not modal).
(I am using this view in CI, so the url is of the controller name, which will call the view for editdialog)

```
<td><a class="linkTo" id="{{record.ID}}" href='<?php echo base_url();?>addEditUsers/{{record.ID}}' style='margin-top:10px;' class='btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-secondary-outline'>Edit</a>
```

**This is what i have done so far.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.linkTo").click(function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        var dialogOpts = {
            title: "View Title",
            modal: true,
            width: "930px",
            resize: "auto",
            close: dialogClosed
        };
        editDialog = $('<div></div>').load("<?php echo site_url("addEditUsers"); ?>", {edit: id})
        .dialog(dialogOpts);
        editDialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

It would be best if I can get the demo of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is .linkTo class?

Comment: Please check now.